# a way to apply the same fx to multiple jquery objects with one call

Tags: jquery

I come from Mootools, and with mootools I could call the same fx to multiple objects with one single call, with smthing like this:

```
$$(obj1,obj2,obj3).tween(...);
```

where obj123 are already 'expanded' dom elements, like $(selector), just like a jQuery object.

It seems that with jQuery this is not possible. You can pass multiple css selectors but you can't pass multiple jQuery objects. I think I'm wrong because it would be quite annoying.. Can't believe it's not possible.

So, what's the jQuery way of doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) for that

```
var one = $(selector1),
    two = $(selector2);

one.add(two).on('click' function() {
    // do stuff
});
```

Comment: @popnoodles - Thanks, not sure why yours was downvoted, it's basically what add() does internally anyway !

Comment: Ok thank you, it's a partial solution. Sad of knowing that jquery doesn't have any smarter way.. But, again, isn't it really strange?

Comment: Mine was obviously downvoted by someone who has absolutely no idea what downvoting is for and who clearly shouldn't have that privilege

Answer (score 0):

Use [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) to add elements to a set of matched elements.

```
var $selector1 = $('#mainbar'),
$selector2 = $('.container'); 
var $common = $selector1.add($selector2);
```

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2vV9H/1/)***

Answer (score -1):

```
obj1=$('#one');
obj2=$('#two');

$.each([obj1, obj2], function(){
    $(this).css({border:"1px solid red"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9kKPV/

This is how I do it. There may be shorter syntax for this. I'd like to know if there is.

Comment: Thank you but that's not what I asked. I asked for a "1 call" syntax like the mootools example. $.each, like _.each and the native forEach are the default 'fallback' way, not the smart one I'm asking for here.